# Query Job Information

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I was looking at the Onscreen Reference to see if there's an XML request for querying jobs. I found that there's just customer query request `CustomerQueryRq` and that too doesn't return the child jobs that it has.

Supposing this is how the customers & jobs centre looks like:

```
- Customer 1
  -- Job 1
  -- Job 2
  -- Job 3
```

I was able to use `CustomerQueryRq` and get the details for `Customer 1`, but couldn't find anything for retrieving `Job 1`.

So my question is how do I query for a job and get the parent customer it's in? I'd really appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** Posting my QBXML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
      <CustomerQueryRq requestID="1">
         <FullName>Customer name</FullName>
      </CustomerQueryRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The `Customer name` has child jobs and I'd like to query those.

Comment: Post your QBXML request.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Posted the QBXML request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ICustomerQuery` returns the list of Jobs along with the Customers list. There isn't a separate query object for Jobs. Each job has a customer as a parent. Hence, you can also retrieve the associated customer for the job. 
Here's an example: I have a job *J1* associated with a customer *C1* in my company file. In the below C# code sample, I create a customer query object (using QB SDK 13.0) and iterate over the results. I get two results in the customer list( C1 and J1 ):

```
using QBXMLRP2Lib;
using Interop.QBFC13;

public class SDKApp
{

private QBSessionManager sessionMgr;

public SDKApp()
{
    // in the class constructor - sessionMgr is a member variable
    sessionMgr = new QBSessionManager(); 
}

public void GetData()
{
// open connection and begin session before data fetch - intentionally skipped this code

// during data fetch
IMsgSetRequest msgset = sessionMgr.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
ICustomerQuery customerQuery = msgset.AppendCustomerQueryRq();
IMsgSetResponse msgRes = sessionMgr.DoRequests(msgset);
IResponseList responseList = msgRes.ResponseList;
if (responseList.Count > 0)
{
    IResponse response = responseList.GetAt(0);
    ICustomerRetList customerList = response.Detail as ICustomerRetList;
    for (int i = 0; i <= customerList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        ICustomerRet qbCustomer = customerList.GetAt(i);
        string displayName = qbCustomer.Name.GetValue();
        string entityType = "Customer";
        if (qbCustomer.ParentRef != null)
        {
            entityType = "Job of " + qbCustomer.ParentRef.FullName.GetValue();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(displayName + " " + entityType);
    }
}

// end session and close connection after data fetch - intentionally skipped this code
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Naveen! Worked great.